# Cabal / Stack - Test Multiple Versions of Dependency

Tags: cabal, haskell-stack

In my project, I have a dependency for which I want to support a wide range of versions, and I want to test each version. Do I need to make a test suite for each version of the dependency, or is there a way I can more easily automate the process of going through each version?

Command line parameters or some other kind of parameterization?

Thanks